# Let the matlab script ask input values?

Tags: matlab

assume (320,190) is the starting point of a bonzai expansion who will spread across the globe

```
bonzai(320,190)=1;
```

that works fine, but i want that matlab asks for the starting point while running the script, so like this:

```
bonzai=input('give lon,lat of the bonzai tree')=1
```

but it doens't work

someone a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You have two equal signs in your expression, i.e. something like `x = y = z`, so this can not work. I would suggest to save the input into a variable, then check if it contains valid entries, and then use this variable to start the expansion:

```
% Get user input
userInput = input('Give lon,lat of the bonzai tree: ');
```

Now, I guess you hope for the user to enter something like `[320,190]`, which is a vector with two values - however you can't be sure about that. So you might want to check, if the user entered a numeric input, and if the user supplied two numbers:

```
% Check if the input is numeric, i.e. a scalar, vector or matrix of numbers
if ~isnumeric(userInput)
    error('Please enter numbers, nothing else!')
end
% Check if the input contains exactly two numbers
if numel(userInput) ~= 2
    error('Please specify two numbers: lon and lat')
end
```

Finally, you are sure, the user entered the numbers in a correct format, and you can use this to initialize `bonzai`:

```
% Initialize bonzai
bonzai(userInput(1),userInput(2)) = 1;
```